# Functional reactive programming — is Fay expressive enough?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, haskell, paradigms

So I'm doing a fairly involved javascript/html client with lots of ajax calls and other involvements of callback-ism. I'm entertaining the thought of using Fay for this purpose. I'm aware of Elm. Tried it and liked the FRP elements. Now I'm looking to know if similar structure is possible in Fay.

Are there any concrete examples of FRP in Fay out there at this point?

Some relevant technologies:

- [Arrowlets](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/arrowlets/), arrowised FRP in javascript
- [FlapJax](http://www.flapjax-lang.org/), another javascript alternative
- [Bacon.js](https://github.com/raimohanska/bacon.js), FRP in javascript

[One possible solution, using Bacon](https://github.com/NicolasT/Bacon-n-Fay). With [demo](http://nicolast.github.com/Bacon-n-Fay/BaconFliesLikeAnArrow.html).

Answer (score 3):

[The ReactiveMvc example among the fay-ide examples](https://github.com/faylang/fay-server/blob/master/src/Language/Fay/ReactiveMvc.hs) is probably the best bet at this moment. Although I'm not sure about the completeness or how it compares to other FRP solutions.

I suspect this does not fill the qualification of *Functional* Reactive Programming. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

At OdHac a couple of people successfully ported a Haskell FRP library to Fay, but I don't think they have released it yet.

Writing an FFI library should be easier, but it depends on the library you are using. Mainly how hard it is to type it. People have experimented with Bacon.js, for instance [Bacon-n-fay](https://github.com/NicolasT/Bacon-n-Fay) (This doesn't compile with the latest version of Fay but I'm guessing it would be easy to update it.)

So yes it's doable, and I hope someone will release a package for it soon.